# Validating UK PostCode with JavaScript Reg for Angular5 app

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-validation

I am working on Angular 5 Reactive Form validation and trying to validate UK PostCode using custom validation function which is working and testing apart from in case provide extra letter or numeric value at end of postcode 2nd part, it validate true, for example NW10 5NW is correct but if I type anything like NW10 5NWRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR is also return true which is not correct.

I have tried following regular experssion on https://regexr.com/ and it return correct response, not sure why in javaScript not behaving same way???

```
function postCodeValidator(control: FormControl)
 {
   let givenPostCode = control.value;

   let UKPostCodePattern = /^([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z]))))\s?[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})/;

   var isUKPostCodeValid = UKPostCodePattern.test(givenPostCode); 

   console.log("postcode validity ",isUKPostCodeValid,  " for ", givenPostCode);

  if(!isUKPostCodeValid)
  {
    return {
        postCode:{
          required:"UK Valid PostCode",
          provided: givenPostCode
        }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I tested it with [Regexr][1]. When I just copied your regex and add /g at the end it worked for me. 

Maybe you can try this?

  [1]: https://regexr.com/3pot9 "Regexr"

Comment: Add a `$` to the end of your regex to force it to match the whole string. You already have the `^` at the start which anchors the beginning of the string; the `$` at the end does the same for the end of the string.

Comment: How about a built in Angular validators?                                                           Exmple: this.address = this.fb.group({
      postCode: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(UKPostCodePattern)]],
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using following regex

```
^(([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z]))))\s?[0-9][A-Za-z]{2}))$
```

https://regexr.com/3pp3r